What WW1 events do Marne, Somme and Argonne refer to on January 1, 1916?
I have a question regarding some battles or other events mentioned in the comic book "L'Ambulance 13: Croix de Sang", which plays in World War I in the French army.
The first scene of the book plays on January 1, 1916, as is clearly stated on the first page. I was confused by a soldier stating (in the German translation that I was reading) that he participated in the "Schlacht an der Somme" (Battle of the Somme), which only took place later that year.
I thought that this might be an issue with the translation and managed to find a sample including the first few pages here. At the top of page 3 you can find the date (1er janvier 1916) and on the last picture on page 5 is the statement that I was mentioning. The relevant part goes like this:

"J'ai fait la Marne, la Somme, l'Argonne et le toutim." ("I did the
Marne, the Somme, the Argonne and all that.")

So, the Somme is also mentioned in the original together with two other locations that might refer to battles or some other events. The first one is most likely referring to the First Battle of the Marne. But both, the Battle of the Somme and the Meuse-Argonne Offensive make no sense given the date.
So, in the end, my questions boils down to this: which battles or other events does the soldier allude to with Marne, Somme and Argonne, given that he does this on January 1, 1916?
The comic book series seems to have a reputation of being well researched. Also, in the second book, on February 20, 1916 the main character is with with the 56th and 59th Bataillons de chasseurs à pied under the command of Emile Driant at Verdun and soon the attack starts, which fits the facts quite well as far as I can tell. I find it hard to imagine that they managed to get this right and at the same time put the Battle of the Somme in the wrong year... –

There is the possibility that the author of the comic simply didn't fact check when picking the date.

@SteveBird Yes, that's certainly a possibility. However, the comic book series seems to have a reputation of being well researched. Also, in the second book, on February 20, 1916 the main character is with with the 56th and 59th Bataillons de chasseurs à pied under the command of Emile Driant at Verdun and soon the attack starts, which fits the facts quite well as far as I can tell. I find it hard to imagine that they managed to get this right and at the same time put the Battle of the Somme in the wrong year...

@Stibu Being careful some of the time doesn't mean you're always carefuk.

Those places have seen battles since summer 1914.... for the somme may it be the battle of St. Quentin (which is on Somme river), while the Argonne may be defensive battle by the 3rd or 4th french army during summer 1914 offensive (retreat around Verdun), but still, in my opinion, it is a mismatch (unless at the time those were the names used by soldiers)

It's just an anachronism by a writer who is adding color to what is essentially a historical novel.
